# React Native route.params is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've been trying to pass data from my home.js screen to my merchant.js screen by using navigation.navigate('Merchant', store ) but when I try to actually use route.params I get undefined.

Here's my home.js

```
export default function Home( { navigation }) {
...
{storeData.map(store => {
    return (
     <View>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.categoryName}
          onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Merchant', store)}}>
         {store.name}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Merchant.js

```
function Merchant({ navigation, route }) {
    console.log(route);
...
}
```

Output:

{"key": "Merchant-86K9u5ytF32VGMRcO9s2g", "name": "Merchant", "params": undefined}

Again I have no idea what is going on. I've tried navigation.push(), I've tried using navigate('Merchant', {name: store.name}) but I still get undefined.

If you would like to paste more code with my stack navigation I can.

Comment: Just for clarification: isn't this about **React Navigation**, not **React Native Navigation**?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/ says that "Pass params to a route by putting them in an object as a second parameter". Did you try passing store between curly braces => {store} instead of store?

Comment: maybe your `store` is undefined, can you console.log it to make sure?

Comment: @ElsonRamos i also thought the same, but i recently tried it on [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/ongfznpk1), it seems to work

Comment: Yes, I've tried using curly braces and yes store isn't undefined.

Comment: Bro, this thing should definitely work, can you provide an expo snack? So we can look into it? Also, tell me what type of data is in `storeData`? (String? Array of strings, Array of objects .....)

Comment: @DaniyalShaikh storeData is an array of objects and also I'm not sure if an expo snack would work because I have a complex structure to my navigation stacks.

Comment: Hey, I've created my snack but now I'm getting an error. Here's the link https://snack.expo.dev/B0Dztrfqt

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

```
navigation.navigate('Merchant', store)
```

Access the value by:

```
navigation.getParam('onePropertyOfStoreHere');
```

Comment: When I tried that it said navigation.getParam is not a function.

Comment: what u are using, navigation from ```@react-navigation/native```? which version u r using?

Comment: I have "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.1"

Comment: it's strange, what u've done is right based on the doc https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/. Maybe if u could create a reproducible snack represents ur code will be helpful for us to trace the issue

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured why it was undefined. It was because I had another stack that started with Merchant.js on the top.

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Merchant" headerShown='false'>
    <Stack.Screen name="Merchant" component={Merchant} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ProductInfo" component={ProductInfo}/>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

This must of confused the app as I was moving from Home to Merchant screen but it went into another stack.